# Implications pf mean dependence in the classical linear model

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model, independence

Consider the classical linear model

(1) $Y_i=X_i'\beta+\epsilon_i$

(2) $(Y_i, X_i)_{i=1}^n$ i.i.d.

(3) $E(\epsilon_i| X_1,..., X_n)=0$

---

Could you help me to show step by step that

(1), $(Y_i, X_i)_{i=1}^n$ mutually independent, (3) $\Rightarrow$ $E(\epsilon_i|X_i)=0$

---

Could you help me to show step by step that

(1), $(Y_i, X_i)_{i=1}^n$ mutually independent, $E(\epsilon_i|X_i)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ (3)

---

Also, is it true that

(1), (2), $\epsilon_i \perp X_i$   $\Rightarrow$ $\epsilon_i \perp (X_1,..., X_n)$

? Why?

Comment: I think this question should have the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [law of iterated
    expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Iterated_expectations_with_nested_conditioning_sets) for the first part
    $$ E(\epsilon_i \mid X_i) = E(E(\epsilon_i \mid X_1, \dots, X_n))\,.$$

For the second, note that $(Y_i, X_i)_1^n$ are mutually independent implies, $(X_i)_1^n$ are mutually independent. In addition, for $A$ and $B$ mutually independent $E(A) = E(A\mid B)$ and vice-versa. So
$$E(\epsilon_i \mid X_i) = E(\epsilon_i \mid X_1, \dots, X_n)\,. $$

For the third,
$\epsilon_i \perp X_i \Rightarrow E(\epsilon_i \mid X_i) = E(\epsilon_i)\,.$ From the previous part, we know that when $(Y_i, X_i)_1^n$ are mutually independent, 
$$E(\epsilon_i \mid X_1, \dots, X_n) = E(\epsilon_i \mid X_i)  = E(\epsilon_i)\,.$$
This gives the required result.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask few clarifications: 1) for the first part it seems that having $(Y_i, X_i)_{i=1}^n$ i.i.d. is not required, correct? 2) for the second, are you using that $\epsilon_i \perp ( X_1,..., X_{i-1}, X_{i+1}, X_n )| X_i$? 3) For the third, are you sure that the relation between independence and mean independence is if and only if? I would say that $\epsilon_i \perp X_i \rightarrow E(\epsilon_i| X_i)=E(\epsilon_i)$ but the converse is not necessarily true. Thank you

Comment: 1) Correct. 2) Yes. 3) You are right, it is generally not true. But it is true under the normality assumption of $\epsilon$. If you are making that assumption, then it is true.

Comment: regarding (3) here I am not making the normality assumption.